# How can i fix the css class that works halfway?

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS class that works halfway, that is, it doesn't see `background-color` and `text-decoration`, but the rest sees it.

This is my css class:

```
btn-group button {
  background-color: "#77DD77";
  text-decoration: "line-through";
  border: 1px solid green; /* Green border */
  color: white; /* White text */
  padding: 10px 24px; /* Some padding */
  cursor: pointer; /* Pointer/hand icon */
  width: 50%; /* Set a width if needed */
  display: block; /* Make the buttons appear below each other */
}
```

This is my html:

```
 <div class="btn-group">
     <ul>
          <todo-item
          v-if="item.clicked==true"
          v-for="item in groceryList"
          v-bind:todo="item"
          v-bind:key="item.id"
          ></todo-item>
     </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: where's the `button` in your html? Is it generated by whatever `todo-item` is?

Comment: You have missed . in your css. It should like: .btn-group

Comment: remove `""` ....

Comment: You don't need to quote the values! Use `#77dd77` NOT `"#77dd77"`... same with `"line-through"`, remove the quotes.

Comment: Voting to Close as this question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
.btn-group button {
  background-color: #77DD77;
  text-decoration: line-through;
  border: 1px solid green; /* Green border */
  color: white; /* White text */
  padding: 10px 24px; /* Some padding */
  cursor: pointer; /* Pointer/hand icon */
  width: 50%; /* Set a width if needed */
  display: block; /* Make the buttons appear below each other */
}
```

Comment: Thanks, he now see text-decoration, but don't see background-color....

Comment: please create jsfiidle of your code which you have tried

Comment: You can see here. background color is showing properly here: https://jsfiddle.net/kyh67fxj/